# Stop two connections from running the same query

Tags: mysql

I am using this query in my site to get the next Auto-Increment but the problem is two or more  connections can run this query at the same time and both of them have the same AUto-Increment value.

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'TABLE_ORDERS';
```

Is there any way I can stop two or more connections from running this query at the same time?

Many Thanks!!

```
Edit
```

The value of this Auto-increment is then used to store records in another table 'Receipts'. And if two connections get the same Auto-increment value from the Orders table, I end up having two rows in the Receipt table with the same value.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Make it the responsibility of the connection. Any application that is allowed to run queries like this should be in your own control anyway.

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify your question. The whole point of auto-increments is that you don't have to worry about managing multiple connections, the db engine insures that each record gets a unique value. You're not supposed to ask for the next auto-increment value and then force it in. Just let the db set it.

Comment: @Jay I have add some more info. May be that will help better explain the situation.

Comment: I see tadman gave the essence of the right answer before I got back to see your update. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the auto-increment values directly as this will invariably lead to the sorts of race conditions you're describing.

Instead you should insert a record and check `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to see which identifier was issued to your row. This value can then be safely transposed into other tables.

The good news is `LAST_INSERT_ID()` values represent the inserted ID of the last row on a per-connection basis so there should be no risk of a race condition there.

Comment: OK I get it. So the problem is not in the code, the problem is the logic I am implementing to get the records from Orders table to Receipt table?

Comment: Perform your `INSERT`, then `SELECT` the inserted ID, then add that as one of the values to your associated records. Later you can select and `JOIN` against these.

Comment: If you're coding in Java, JDBC has a built-in function to retrieve the generated key -- Statement.getGeneratedKeys. I prefer to use that over a db-specific method as it allows me to use the same method regardless of which db engine I'm using -- fewer things to learn. If whatever programming language you're using doesn't have a built-in function, you have to use the db-specific method, as tadman describes.

Comment: If you have a driver, by all means use the appropriate driver method for portability reasons. The original question wasn't clear on platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can put that in a stored procedure and add a

```
SELECT SLEEP(2);
```

in it.

> which is useful when a previous query needs to be paused, say, when a slave is reconnecting to a master.

[MySQL SLEEP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep)

Comment: Sorry I had a different question in mind and ended up asking something else. I have made the change now. Thanks.